# How to overwrite default IOS dropdown?

Tags: html, ios, css, styles

i'm wondering if it's possible to overwrite the option style tag for IOS. I know you can replace the styles for the select tag with -webkit-appearance: none, but what about the option tag. Is there any way to change the background color? Javascript solutions are welcomed too.

Comment: Maybe what you need is restyle the whole select option elements. Bootstrap provided a solution please take a look: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Comment: yea, i saw this before but what if we're already so deep in a project in wordpress. Client says it needs to be standardized on all browsers and OS. So if i were to implement this, i should hide the real form and link the bootstrap form to the real form. Sounds so troublesome. D:

Comment: Please have a look at this jQuery plugin and see if it's gonna help: http://hernansartorio.com/jquery-nice-select/